# loop through multiple return redirect in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using python flask to create a tool where ppl can upload files and these files are then splitted into multiple files based on some criteria.  I am at the point, where the file can be uploaded and splitted and want to get to back to the users.

My script loops through a list, in this case the list contains ['1','2','3] and saves three files, file_1.csv, file_2.csv and file_3.csv.

The problem I am stuck with is how to push the multiple (in current case three, but that number can change) back to the user.

With my current code, see below (for i in .... return redirect...), I only get 1 file (file_1.csv), but expect all three, one after each other.

Anyone able to spot my error? :)

```
        for i in rank_list: 
            new = df[df["Rank"] == i]
            new.to_csv(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY+'/file_'+str(round(i))+'.csv')  
            time.sleep(3)
            return redirect('/download/file_'+str(round(i))+'.csv')




@app.route('/download/<path:path>',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_files(path):
try:
    return send_from_directory(DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY, path, as_attachment=True)
except FileNotFoundError:
    abort(404)
```

Comment: Please check your code. And add some context about the Flask code. It seems Flask is used to dealing with a HTML form and retrieves the files from request.files and answers a HTML page containing the multiple processed files : right ?

With send_from_directory it sends 1 and only 1 file. If you want to return multiple files, you could provide a zip/tar/other-archive file. Or else you can provide a HTML page with links to download each file.

Comment: hm ok, thought it might be a bit easier but yeah can create an html with the files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `return` command in a for loop. The problem is that `return` can only happen once. If you want to return multiple values, then you have to put them in a list, return the list and then process the list (loop through them) on the front end